# HDMI audio output disconnected if TV is turned on after resume from suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have a PC which turns on and off connected TV using USB relay.
When I suspend the PC, relay turns off and when I resume, relay turns on (/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ script).

But after resume, HDMI audio output shows as disconnected (video works). Even if I physically reconnect the HDMI cable, it still shows as disconnected. Only way to make it work again is to reboot the PC.

I have 4th gen Intel i3, integrated GPU, fresh Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS install.

Is there I way I cound fix it without reboot?

These didn't work:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

killall pulseaudio; rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -rf ~/.pulse*

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1

/etc/pulse/default.pa
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Also this maybe related, maybe off topic issue:
Video output is black if I boot up the PC and then turn on the TV (startup script again).

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been pulling my hairs out on this one.

Comment: The PC controls power relay through USB. The relay controls power to the TV. PC's video output to the TV is HDMI.
USB power relay is probably irrelevant. Basically if I turn on TV before resuming PC from suspend, HDMI audio is disconnected.

Comment: Of course I wrote it the other way...
If I resume the PC before powering on the TV, HDMI audio is disconnected.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying it without the relay. If I suspend PC, turn off TV, resume PC, turn on TV, the audio is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying other distributions and with Gnome had the same issue. Then I tried few with KDE Plasma and it's not issue there.
So my "solution" is to not use Gnome...